# Can't set tab bar icon iOS

Tags: ios, uiimage, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have a UITabBarController with a tab bar (of course), and I'm trying to set custom images to the tabs on my tab bar with the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    UITabBar *menuTab = self.tabBarController.tabBar;

    UIImage *friendImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"friends_tab@2x.png"];
    UIImage *friendImageSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"friends_tab_selected@2x.png"];

    UITabBarItem *friendItem = [menuTab.items objectAtIndex:1];
    [friendItem initWithTitle:@"Friends" image:friendImage selectedImage:friendImageSelected];

}
```

on the `[friendItem initWithTitle:@"Friends" image:friendImage selectedImage:friendImageSelected];` code line, i'm getting a warning "Expression Result unused" and the tab item neither get the image I set nor the text.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the items in a `UITabBar` that way. Basically, once a `UITabBarItem` is created, it's read-only. (The only exceptions to this are `badgeValue`, `selectedImage`, and title positioning.)

Also, you're getting the warning you are because `init...` methods returns a value, which you're not using. Calling `init...` methods on an existing object is just wrong.

Instead, what you need to do it something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIViewController *vc            = self.viewControllers[1];
    UIImage *friendImage            = [UIImage imageNamed:@"friends_tab"];
    UIImage *friendImageSelected    = [UIImage imageNamed:@"friends_tab_selected"];
    UITabBarItem *friendItem        = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Friends" image:friendImage selectedImage:friendImageSelected];
    vc.tabBarItem                   = friendItem;
}
```

Notice that I create a ***completely*** new `UITabBarItem`. When you have a `UITabBarController`, you are unable to have access to its `UITabBar` in the same way as one you create and manage yourself. Therefore, you need to access the `tabBarItem` property of the `UIViewController` you wish to modify.

Comment: I just tried your code, indeed it makes sense, but for some reason it doesn't work...

Comment: UITabBar *menuTab               = self.tabBarController.tabBar;
Returns nil... which fails the whole code... I need to find another way to access it

Comment: What's your navigational structure? Perhaps you need to get the navigationController first?

Comment: What do you means with "navigational structure"? It's a class which is a subclass of UITabBarController set to a TabBarViewController on the storyboard

Comment: The Weird thing is that on debugging, self > UITabBarController > UIViewController > ... everything inside is nil

Comment: Then it sounds like `self` is **already** the `UITabBarController`, meaning you can just use `self.tabBar`, right?

Comment: Yes, now UITabBar *menuTab               = self.tabBar; is returning something, but when I get to [menuTab setItems:[items copy] animated:NO];

the app crashes with the message "'Directly modifying a tab bar managed by a tab bar controller is not allowed.'"

Comment: Ok. I misunderstood your structure. See my edited answer. You should be able to replace the `tabBarItem` property on the `UIViewController` in the `viewControllers` array of `UITabBarController`.

Answer (score -1):

You have already initialized your friend item--it was already made and you are retrieving it. You need to remove your initWithImage line andchange the title and image like properties, for example:

```
[friendItem setImage:@"myImage"];
```

and you can do the same for the title and the selected image. Does this work?

Comment: `UITabBarItem` objects are not mutable after creation. Please see my answer.